# Trying to tidy data but get errors: can't convert .x[[i]] empty character vector to a function & must extract column with a single valid subscript

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to tidy a dataset where I measured exposure at two different stations by time (in seconds). I have a data frame which has column 1 as Second, column 2 as SiteA_Number (corresponding to the number of particles at SiteA), SiteA_Diamater (diameter of particles at SiteA), SiteA_LDSA (LDSA at SiteA), and the same measurements for SiteB as 3 more columns (SiteB_Number, SiteB_Diam, SiteB_LDSA).

I would like my dataset to transform to have a column for the Seconds, columns for Number, Diameter, and LDSA, and a separate column for the station (SiteA or SiteB). That way, I can plot a graph with Number (y axis) over time (seconds) and fill by site.

The structure of each column is as follows:

```
'data.frame':   1800 obs. of  7 variables:
$ Second: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ SiteA_Number : int  16673 19891 20370 17513 18185 18982 18362 17579 16605 15590 ...
$ SiteA_Diam : int  41 39 38 42 41 39 40 42 44 45 ...
$ SiteA_LDSA  : num  36.1 40.4 40.7 38.6 38.8 ...
$ SiteB_Number: int  15554 16745 17719 16494 15811 15331 16053 16196 15733 15521 ...
$ SiteB_Diam  : int  40 39 37 40 42 44 42 42 42 43 ...
$ SiteB_LDSA  : num  33 33.8 34.3 34.2 35.2 ...
```

I tried using pivot_longer to create a station column and then corresponding columns for the number, diameter, and LDSA:

```
MergedLDSA %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Second,
    names_to =c("Station", ".value"),
    names_sep = ("_"),
    names_transform = list(
      Number = as.integer,
      Diameter = as.integer,
      LDSA = as.integer,
      Station = as.character())
  )
```

But I get the error message:

```
Error in `map()`:
! Can't convert
  `.x[[i]]`, an empty
  character vector, to
  a function.
```

I then tried using the separate() function:

```
MergedLDSA %>% 
  separate(c(SiteA_Number, SiteA_Diam, SiteA_LDSA, SiteB_Number, SiteB_Diam, SiteB_LDSA), into = c("Station", ".value"), sep = "_")
```

But I get the error message:

```
Error:
! Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `var` has size 6 but must be size 1.
```

I'm fairly beginner at coding and this is my first time trying to tidy real data. I do not understand the errors and cannot figure out how to tidy my data the way I'd like.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(head(MergedLDSA))`.

Comment: In `pivot_longer` try removing the extra parentheses after `as.character` for the `names_transform` argument...use `as.character` and not `as.character()`...

Comment: > dput(head(MergedLDSA))
structure(list(Second = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), SiteA_Number = c(16673L, 
19891L, 20370L, 17513L, 18185L, 18982L), SiteA__Diam = c(41L, 39L, 
38L, 42L, 41L, 39L), SiteA__LDSA = c(36.08, 40.37, 40.71, 38.57, 
38.8, 38.94), SiteB_Number = c(15554L, 16745L, 17719L, 16494L, 
15811L, 15331L), SiteB_Diam = c(40L, 39L, 37L, 40L, 42L, 44L), 
    SiteB_LDSA = c(33.02, 33.83, 34.29, 34.18, 35.16, 35.31)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Removing the brackets after as.character worked! Thank you for your help!